# Need help with Dispatcher.PushFrame style process blocking in WPF page

Tags: wpf

I am using Dispatcher.PushFrame to block my code while allowing the UI to refresh until a long running process is done.  This works as expected, so long as my call to Dispatcher.PushFrame is from a button click event.  If, however, I use this same code during the Page’s Loaded event or constructor, the UI does not refresh, and so never paints.  As a random experiment, I tried using Window.ShowDialog from the constructor, and it does allow the UI to paint, even though control is blocked until the modal dialog closes.  Can anyone offer a solution to allow this functionality from the Page Loaded event using Dispatcher.PushFrame or some other manual mechanism?

As an addendum, if I minimize or maximize my window, the UI paints and I can interact with it normally, but not until I manually perform the resize.

Comment: if anyone cares, there's some more background info on this question over at the [msdn forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/e2c85fa9-09c2-4eb1-bdd7-78d8f2d6aaf3). (it's even marked as answered there...)

Comment: @user598946, your question really was answered in the MSDN forums.  Is there anything in that answer that you are not clear about?

Answer (score 3):

From my readings in MSDN on [Object Lifetime Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx) and stumping around in Reflector it appears that the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events are not raised in the same manner as other events. Internally a `BroadcastEventHelper` class is used, which coordinates the various `Loaded` events amongst every element in the visual tree before eventually raising them at the `DispatcherPriority.Loaded` level.

I believe this is why you're seeing this behavior.

As for a concrete solution, I suggest long running tasks not be placed in the `Page.Loaded` event handler and instead a `BackgroundWorker` or `Task` be issued to complete the work.